# Python singleton with inheritence

Tags: python, inheritance, reference, singleton

I have a singleton:

```
class ClassStn(BaseClass):
    INSTANCE = None

    def __init__(self, x1, args = None):
        if self.INSTANCE is not None:
            raise ValueError("An instantiation already exists!")

        # initializing
        BaseClass.__init__(self)
        self.x1 = x1
        self.args = args

    @classmethod
    def get_instance(cls, x1, args):
        if cls.INSTANCE is None:
            cls.INSTANCE = ClassStn(x1, args)
        return cls.INSTANCE
```

Should `BaseClass` be a singleton as well? I'm concern that the reference to a singleton that inherits a non singleton class may be messed up

Comment: I don't think that base class should be singleton here.

Answer (score 1):

**No**. Say for example that your `BaseClass` is an `Nameable`: a class that simply specifies that an object has a name. Then you can have several things that have a name `Human`, `Cat`, `Dog`. But `God` for instance is a singleton (in monotheistic religions). So then `God` is a singleton, but `Nameable` is not. Only if there is one instance of `Nameable` should `Nameable` be a singleton. But that would make subclassing weird.

That being said, singletons are usually considered *anti-pattern*: a sign that some logic is not really right in your program. So before making something a singleton, you better think twice whether that is necessary.

Furthermore in case you want to implement a singleton, you can override the `__new__` method:

```
class ClassStn(BaseClass):

    INSTANCE = None

    def __init__(self, x1, args = None):
        super().__init__(self)
        self.x1 = x1
        self.args = args

    def __new__(cls,*args,**kwargs):
        if ClassStn.INSTANCE is None:
            ClassStn.INSTANCE = super().__new__(cls,*args,**kwargs)
        return ClassStn.INSTANCE
```

Now invoking the constructor will construct the singleton the first time, and invoking it a second time, will return a *reference* to the same object. So:

```
x = ClassStn()
y = ClassStn()
```

Will produce one singleton, and `x` and `y` will refer to that singleton.

Finally note that **singleton constructors usually do not have parameters**. Since that would defeat the purpose of these parameters: if you construct an object based on the value of one argument, then it is weird that you can construct only one object, since different parameters should usually result in a different object.